# Hack into .getUrl() method of an entry

Tags: templating

Due to some SEO and infrastructure issues I would like to be able to intercept the getUrl() method of entries and modify its return value.

e.g.

```
<a href="{{ entry.getUrl() }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
```

would normally return

```
<a href="/whatever/here">Whatever Here Title</a>
```

but I want the same TWIG Code to ouput

```
<a href="/whatever/here?x-something-dynamic=dynamic-value">Whatever Here Title</a>
```

Is this possible with a module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using the `EVENT_AFTER_POPULATE_ELEMENT` event to override entries' `uri` property:

```php
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\elements\db\ElementQuery;
use craft\elements\db\EntryQuery;
use craft\events\PopulateElementEvent;

Event::on(
    EntryQuery::class,
    ElementQuery::EVENT_AFTER_POPULATE_ELEMENT,
    static function (PopulateElementEvent $event) {
       $entry = $event->element;
       if (!$entry->uri) {
          return;
       }
       $entry->uri = $entry->uri . '?x-something-dynamic=dynamic-value';
    }
);
```

Beware that this will add the query string to entry URIs *everywhere*, though (including inside the control panel, i.e. for the "View" button and any links inside entry indexes).

If you only want it to occur for Twig templates (i.e. frontend requests), you might want to do something like

```php
...
if (!$entry->uri || !Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsSiteRequest()) {
   return;
}
...
```